# Close Bootstrap's modal with AJAX

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I use the modal of [Twitter's Bootstrap.](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals)
You can close the modal, by clicking on a button or something different with the tag `data-dismiss="modal"`.
I would like to process my form in the modal with AJAX (by clicking on a submit button) and then close the modal.
So how do close this modal in AJAX?
Or is that not possible?

(sorry for my bad English...)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you read further down the documentation:

```
$('#myModal').modal('hide')
```

Just get the ID of the modal, and replace `myModal` with it. Then place it in the AJAX success handler and there you have it.

Comment: Thanks! Thats JavaScript? Can I use it in AJAX?

Comment: Place `$('.modal').each(function(){$(this).modal('hide');});` in the `success` function of your ajax call. This will hide all modal's without having to specify them individually by ID.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this script to close the modal

```
<button type="button" id="close_btn" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
    <i class = "icons-office-52"></i> 
</button> 
    $("#close_btn").trigger("click");
```

or

```
$('#my_model').modal('hide');
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error and comparing the HTML before and after I have arrived at the following which works:

```
$('body').removeAttr("style");
$("#myModal").removeAttr("style");
$(".modal-backdrop").remove();
```