# Close Modal Pop up after submit message in server side

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, bootstrap-modal

I have a `bootstrap modal pop up`. Inside that there are many controls and submit button. So after successfully submitting I want to close that pop up. Below is the code which shows the message as `Record Saved successfully`.

```
if (strMessage == "Success" && strSaveSubmit == "Draft")
            {
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "erroralert", "alert('Record Saved as Draft Successfully');", true);                    
            }
```

But with this, I want to close the modal popup which I am unable to. here is that div

```html
<div class="modals">

        <form id="frmFileUpload" runat="server">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnFileInfo" runat="server" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnClose" runat="server" />
                <label>Sap ID</label>
                <asp:Label ID="lblSapId" Text="" runat="server" />
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label>Candidate ID</label>
                <asp:Label ID="lblCandidateId" Text="" runat="server" />
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label>Technical Feasible</label>
                <div class="selectWraper">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTechFeasible" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="Select" />
                        <asp:ListItem Text="YES" Value="YES" />
                        <asp:ListItem Text="NO" Value="NO" />
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="upload">
                    <label>Upload Document</label>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnGetFileName" runat="server" />
                    <div id="dvFileUpload">
                        <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="flufileUpload" AllowMultiple="true" CssClass="chooseFile" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label>Remarks</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtRemarks" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="overflow: auto; height: 100px;">

                <asp:GridView ID="grdFilesInfo" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" EmptyDataText="No files uploaded">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Text" HeaderText="Uploaded Files" />
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" ToolTip="download files" CssClass="fa fa-download" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Value") %>' runat="server" OnClick="lnkDownload_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" ToolTip="delete files" CssClass="fa fa-trash-o" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Value") %>' runat="server" OnClientClick="if (!confirm('Are you sure you want delete the file?')) return false;" OnClick="lnkDelete_Click" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </div>

            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="modalButton">

                <asp:Button ID="btnSaveDraft" runat="server" Text="Save as Draft" OnClick="btnSaveDraft_Click" CssClass="button" OnClientClick="return SaveOrDraft('Draft');" />

                <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" data-dismiss="modal" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" CssClass="button" OnClientClick="return SaveOrDraft('Draft');" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

JQuery and Ajax are your friend here.

You could just add this inside a document.ready...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#<%= btnSubmit.ClientID %>').on('click', function () {
        $('.modals').hide(); // hides anything with 'modals' as the class
    }
}
```

You could also just give the modal an ID and use $('#ModalID').hide();
You could assign a static id to the submit button, but the <%= btnSubmit.ClientID %> will pull out the ID for you.

Is this an ajax operation?  From the code you have there it looks like it would perform a postback and reload the page anyway.

Comment: I want it server side.

Comment: Typically what happens is you submit a request to the server via an Ajax call.  The server still performs all the functions and returns a response.  The modal is being presented to the user on the client's side.  You might have to rethink your workflow a little bit for maximum flexibility and control. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19596734/close-bootstraps-modal-with-ajax

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ShowHide-OpenClose-AJAX-Modal-Popup-using-JavaScript-in-ASPNet.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```html
if (strMessage == "Success" && strSaveSubmit == "Draft")
            {
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "erroralert", "alert('Record Saved as Draft Successfully');", true);  
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Popup", "closePopUP();", true);                
            }
            
function closePopUP(){

 $(".modals").modal('hide');
}
```